# Is the Gödel sentence of Dan Willard's self-verifying theories a $Π_1$ sentence?

Tags: logic

Dan Willard proved that you can have weak formal systems than can prove their own consistency, thus avoiding Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

But although Willard's theories can avoid Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, they cannot avoid Gödel's *first* incompleteness theorem: namely, there will always be a sentence expressible in the language of the system that is unprovable in this same system.

My question then is only the following: is the Gödel sentence of Willard's theories a $Π_1$ sentence? For conventional 'stronger' theories, the Gödel sentence will indeed be $Π_1$, but is it also the same for these weaker Willard theories?